# resizing browser slow in complex dojo layout for FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo

I have a relatively complex, but pretty typical I'd assume, layout using dojo 1.6.1.

It loads up quick enough but when I resize the browser, it take a bit of time for the layout to catch up.  The strange thing is that the resizing is lightning fast on IE6 for a change.

The following is the partial HTML showing the structured:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" id="page">
        <div dojoType="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" region="top">
            <div id="mainheader" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">Page Header</div>
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" region="center">
            <div dojoType="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" region="left" style="width: 20em;">
                <div id="mainnav" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left">Page Nav</div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" region="center">
                    <div dojoType="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" region="top">
                        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">Main Top</div>
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center" tabStrip="true">
                        <div id="maincontent" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" href="large_data.htm" title="Tab 1">
                        </div>
                        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab 2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The effect is more dramatic as the data that gets loaded up into one of the tab panes, gets larger.  It doesn't have to be too large - any sizable HTML table will do the job.

I know I have some redundant layout components in there which I can remove.  But the speed gain isn't all that much.

If I put a single BorderContainer and a ContentPane and load up the data in there, the resize is obviously quick enough (although still not as fast as IE6!)

Note that I've tried using time-delayed resizing (i.e. debouncing) as well with not so much benefit.

If anyone can provide insights into why this happens or a workaround, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It's hard to say without having the actual page... if you can post a link to one, I can probably tell you at least why it happens.